# How to config file conposer.json for namespace Module magento2?

Tags: magento2, composer, marketplace

I tried use to validate_m2_package.php to confign my module for Magento 2 upto marketplace. 
This is structure my folder:

```
Namespace
---- ModuleBase
------ composer.json
------ registration.php
---- ModuleName
------ composer.json
------ registration.php
composer.json ? i need know content this file.
```

After zipfile : **Namespace.zip**. It not success. Pls help me guide file composer.json in folder Namespace.

Many thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

```
{
"name": "company_name/module_name",
"description": "module description here",
"require": {
    "php": "~5.5.0|~5.6.0|~7.0.0",
    "magento/module-config": "100.0.*",
    "magento/module-store": "100.0.*",
    "magento/module-backend": "100.0.*",
    "magento/framework": "100.0.*"
},
"type": "magento2-module",
"version": "your module version",
"license": [
    "OSL-3.0",
    "AFL-3.0"
],
"autoload": {
    "files": [
        "registration.php"
    ],
    "psr-4": {
        "COMPANY_NAME\\MODULE_NAME\\": ""
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks @AsharRiaz. it only true with only one module. Ex: ModuleName.Zip. I **updated** structure  folder in my question.

Comment: you can add on module in require:{ } of composer

Comment: If i add require:{... namespace/moduleA: "100.0.*"... }  in file composer.js. How to auto get source of namespace/moduleA. If u can give me sample code of file composer.js  for this's good.

Comment: if module A not exists then it only tells you that module A is missing.

Comment: you have to install both modules separately and both have different composer